# can anyone explain <-> in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

new to typescript can anyone explain what is the meaning of this sign <->? 
Just to confrim, ProductList is actually a function?
in the following code.

```html
export const ProductList: React.FC<-> = ({
  displayLoader,
  hasNextPage,
  notFound,
  onLoadMore,
  products,
  totalCount,
}) => {
  const hasProducts = !!totalCount;

  return (
    <div className="products-list">
      <div className="products-list__products container">
        {hasProducts ? (
          <>
            <div className="products-list__products__grid">
              {products.map(product => (
                <Link
                  to={generateProductUrl(product.id, product.name)}
                  key={product.id}
                >
                  <ProductListItem product={product} />
                </Link>
              ))}
            </div>
            <div className="products-list__products__load-more">
              {displayLoader ? (
                <Loader />
              ) : (
                hasNextPage && (
                  <Button secondary onClick={onLoadMore}>
                    Load more products
                  </Button>
                )
              )}
            </div>
          </>
        ) : (
          <div className="products-list__products-not-found">{notFound}</div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Please advice. Thank you so much.

Comment: Where are you getting this code from?  Have you actually tried running it or compiling it?  It should fail to compile: a dash `-` is not a valid type identifier so the code seems to be ill-formed.  It's hard to tell what it's supposed to be doing without a [mcve], though, so I'm not sure how to advise here.  I think we need more context.  Without it, the answer is just "it's not valid TypeScript so it doesn't mean anything"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be an `interface` that will describe a shape of your props object instead of `-`. Should look something like this  `React.FC<IProductListProps>`. You might get that mistake while copy-pasting. There is no such operator like this `<->` in TypeScript

Comment: I didn’t made any mistake <—>

Comment: Again there is no such thing like <-> in TypeScript. Those "triangles" are used with Generics to define type of generic function/class/interface etc.